# The difference between dollar sign ($) and number (or hash) sign (#) in Prolog

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

As I found I can use from `$` and `#` in the shortened version of the `suspend` in Prolog. Hence, I can write the following query:

```
?- X $> 2, X = 2.5.
```

And the result is:

```
X = 2.5
Yes (0.11s cpu)
```

So what is the difference between `#` and `$` and why the result of the following query:

```
?- X #> 2, X = 2.5.
```

is:

```
No (0.02s cpu)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them used for the suspension in the prolog in `lib(suspend)`. However, **the difference** is `$` for the real numbers and `#` is for integers. Hence, the query `X #> 2, X = 2.5.` was rejected. For example for the query of `X #> 2, X = 3.` you will get `yes` and it is the same for the general case `X $> 2, X = 3.`

Comment: This is implementation and library specific behaviour. You should tag your question appropriately, mention what libraries are loaded, etc.

Comment: @User9213 as mentioned in the question it is in the `lib(suspend)`. BTW, the answer is updated.

Comment: I don't even know which Prolog this is. GNU-Prolog? SWI? SICSTUS? something else?

Comment: Really, SWI-Prolog? Can you link to the documentation? I didn't find it either in the standard library nor in the packages nor in the user-submitted packs :-( I would really like to know where it is hiding.

Comment: @User9213 Indeed it's in the ECLiPse libraries http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/suspend/index.html

Comment: The convention of using # to indicate operations on integers and $ to indicate operations on reals is used in several other of ECLiPSe's constraint-related libraries, e.g. the interval solver http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic and the linear programming solver http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/eplex